# Creating .deb to install bash script program

Tags: bash, ubuntu, installation, debian, deb

I was wondering if the following is possible.

I have a BASH script that I want to make available for some people but I wanted them to only have to "install" the program and not messing around with terminal, so I thought a .deb would be cool.

So what would the "install" do?

Simple. I want to move the script and an icon to a folder (any folder, but I was wondering some hidden folder in Home) and then run a script that creates a launcher in the Applications menu for the first script. It seems there isn't much to it, but for what I've searched, there doesn't seem to be a lot of info...

How can I accomplish this?

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically (install and) run [`dh-make`](http://man.he.net/man8/dh_make) to set up the `debian/` directory, edit the generated files (mainly remove the many you do not need, and fill in a package description and any dependencies in `debian/control`), then [`debuild`](http://man.he.net/man1/debuild)`-us -uc -b`.

You may also have to set up a simple `Makefile` for `debian/rules` to call; it probably only needs an `install` target to copy the binary to `$(DESTDIR)/usr/bin`.

Binaries install into `/usr/bin` and you should not try to override that.  The way to have a menu is to add a [`.desktop` file](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.0.html).

Once you have a good `.deb` you will need to set up a repo for distributing it.  The simplest solution is probably to set up a [launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net/) account and create a personal PPA there.

It's not hard to find more information on these topics, but of course, you need to know what to look for.  The canonical documentation is the [Debian New Maintainer's Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/index.en.html).

Comment: The question is way more broad than can be answered in a SO question, but links to the NMG is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Found this video on youtube that explains IN FULL the process of creating a *.deb for a script or program and even mentions how to do it for a C program.

[Full guide in how to build simple *.deb package](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhoRyd2CEVs&feature=my_watch_later_videos&%20list=WL6225713F0A272584)

Has one bug, btw, that the author, during the making of the *.deb, didn't notice. The path in the *.desktop file for the EXEC parameter is wrong in the example.

Comment: Youtube videos are not a suitable answering format for this platform.